# Finding a DLL SQL Assembly with only the Database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, assemblies

How do I find a DLL for a SQL Assembly in SQL Server if I only have the database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    assembly = a.name, 
    path     = f.name
FROM sys.assemblies AS a
INNER JOIN sys.assembly_files AS f
ON a.assembly_id = f.assembly_id
WHERE a.is_user_defined = 1;
```

Comment: This will only show where the assembly was loaded from, at the time the assmebly was loaded. There is no guarantee that the original file will still be there...

Comment: Well sure, if you delete the file, there is no finding it whatsoever, right? If you've simply moved the file, then at least this gives you a clue of what to search for. If the DLL is no longer correctly loaded, though, not sure what good it is to you even if you do find it... you'd still need the code to create the assembly around it, the functions/procedures that use it, etc. This is why source control trumps afterthought DMV queries.

Comment: true but it helps me find out where they are on the devserver that maybe its still there